# Non standard types with JNA

Tags: java, c, types, jna

I would like to call DLL functions using JNA but the library uses non standard C types.

I can see in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) what it is the [mapping between C and Java standard types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Mapping_types) but, what is it happening with custom types?

Comment: This is like saying "I would like to buy a flying toaster.  I have looked in all the stores and there are plenty of toasters, but what is happening with flying toasters?"  Well, ***nobody sells any.*** what did you expect?

Comment: Care to provide any of these custom types in question?  If you don't understand how types are defined in C, it'd be worth a refresher.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper in C/C++. This wrapper includes the header that defines the custom types. The new wrapper function should accept only standard types as input and "translate" to custom types before calling the library function, in the same way the returned value can also be translated.  Now call your wrapper function from Java via JNA.

Otherwise you could always look into SWIG and JNI.

Comment: Thank you @visibleman . I think JNA is better than JNI, right?

Comment: @Amparo from [JNA's project page](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna): "_JNA uses a small JNI library stub to dynamically invoke native code. The developer uses a Java interface to describe functions and structures in the target native library. This makes it quite easy to take advantage of native platform features **without incurring the high overhead of configuring and building JNI code for multiple platforms.**_"

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of Java classes to architecture dependant types **is preciselly** the purpose of the JNI library.  Think of it as an interface library only, with maps the classes and types passed to a JNI call into the types and classes of a C or C++ program, so expect non-standard issues on doing that.

Think that interfacing to linux/gcc should be a bit different to interfacing to Windows/VisualStudio, for example.

Anyway, the guys at Oracle(former Sun Microsystems) have done a good work, trying to hide the most of the architecture dependant code and trying to be as standard as possible.

My gratitude to them from here :)